# how to implement jquery.FloatThread plugin in my code

Tags: jquery, html, css

please help me with instructions for using jquery.FloatThread plugin in my below code

```css
#container{
  }
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <table  border="1">
 <tr>
 <th width=100 >A</th> <th width=100>B</th> <th width=150>C</th>
 </tr>
<tbody >
<tr>
<td width=100>&nbsp;dfg</td>
<td width=100>&nbsp;dfg</td>
<td width=150>&nbsp;fg</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;ere</td>
<td>&nbsp;fgrty</td>
<td>&nbsp;dfd</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;dfd</td>
<td>&nbsp;dfet</td>
<td>&nbsp;dfdf</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;xzcvc</td>
<tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I didn't get where to implement 'table.demo' found in below code in my code

```
var $table = $('table.demo');
```

$table.floatThead();

Answer (score 0):

Put the row containing the TH's inside a THEAD block.

> I didn't get where to implement 'table.demo' found in below code in my code

Run it using $("#yourTableID").floatThead();